# The Littles Go To War

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, creature-size

**I'm curious if anyone has seen or developed their own rules for combat with characters six inches tall in DnD5e?**

It seems to me that the UA Tiny rules don't quite cover it, at least to my satisfaction.

My players have been shrunk. They are escaping the evil lord's hall and seeking a cure for their curse.

Right now I'm reclassifying monsters based on the size of the PCs. For example, I'm using Lion stats for a Common Rat, and Young Dragon stats for a big Tom Cat (minus the breath weapon and magical perks of course.)

In addition, I've scaled down spell effects to inches instead of feet.

If they face an enemy of regular proportions, I'm multiplying/dividing the damage by 10. Seriously dangerous stuff, but fitting I think.

Also giving auto advantage on Stealth vs. Bigs.

Very curious to see what others think, and have come up with.

Comment: A post like this is—a prompt to share ideas—is great on a discussion site, but RPG.se isn't a discussion site, but a Q&A site. (For more, see our help centre article [“What types of questions should I avoid asking?”](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).) For this kind of post you want a discussion site instead. RPG.se is often mistaken for a discussion site, so we have [a list of RPG discussion sites](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449) to redirect posters to in situations like this. If you have a problem to solve we'd love to help, but if not, one of those should do. Cheers!

Comment: This is fun question, where did you repost?

Comment: I reposted here http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?546710-The-Littles-Go-To-War-Tiny-Combat-Alternatives but didn't get a response.